# How to check if font-face feature is available via javascript

Tags: javascript, font-face

There is a way to check whether font-face feature is available or not through javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for **[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com)**.

Comment: Thanks! how it works? what's happen if font-face is not available?

Comment: Pugia: If font-face is not available, you wont get the 'font-face' class added to your body element...which then allows you to apply corrective css accordingly